# How to check if keyname already exists in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

I need to check if keypair already exists or not. Currently I am using create_key_pair but it throws an error if the key already exists. What is the function to check if keyname already exists or not? Similary with security groups.

Answer (score 1):

Use `describe_key_pairs`.  You can optionally filter for your `key-name` in the call.  See if your key pair is in the result list.